# WKWebView.EvaluateJavaScript never returns

Tags: javascript, c#, ios, xamarin, wkwebview

I'm trying to get a value from my javascript code back to my application using `WKWebView.EvaluateJavaScript(string, WKJavascriptEvaluationResult)`. The problem is, the delegate `WKJavascriptEvaluationResult` is never called. Here's my code:

C#:

```
TaskCompletionSource<NSObject> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<NSObject>();

webView.EvaluateJavaScript(javascript, (result, error) =>
    {
        tcs.SetResult(result);
    });

return tcs.Task.Result;
```

Javascript:

```
function a()
{
    return "test";
}

a();
```

The application is stuck on the `Wait()` call and never returns because the `WKJavascriptEvaluationResult` never gets called. Is there a know issue that I'm not aware of? Is there a better way to get values from my javascript code to my application, or am I not using it correctly?

Note: I'm using a TaskCompletionSource simply to make the whole method synchronous.

Comment: I am seeing a very similar problem. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

Worked for me in Xamarin Forms should be the same if you are using Xamarin IOS.

```
    public class IosWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<HybridWebView, WKWebView>
    {
        const string HtmlCode = "document.body.outerHTML";

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<HybridWebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control == null)
            {
                WKWebView wKWebView = new WKWebView(Frame, new WKWebViewConfiguration());
                wKWebView.NavigationDelegate = new WebViewDelate();
                SetNativeControl(wKWebView);
            }
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                NSUrlRequest nSUrlRequest = new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(hybridWebView.Uri.ToString()));
                Control.LoadRequest(nSUrlRequest);
            }
        }

        class WebViewDelate : WKNavigationDelegate
        {
            public override void DidFinishNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
            {
                WKJavascriptEvaluationResult handler = (NSObject result, NSError error) => {
                    if (error != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
                    }
                };
                webView.EvaluateJavaScript(HtmlCode, handler);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Dude nice answer but it should be `if (error == null)`

Comment: @gneric I guess its correct ..  just displaying the result if error is not null.. lmk

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use method EvaluateJavaScriptAsync instead of EvaluateJavaScript? I think it leads to much better readability of code - and it might even uses a TaskCompletionSource under the hood :)

```
try
{
    var obj = await Control.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync(js).ConfigureAwait(true);
    if (obj != null)
        response = obj.ToString();
}
catch (Exception) { /* The Webview might not be ready... */ }
```