# EvaluatejavaScrip in IOS Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I use the following code to run javascript on iOS's WkWebView,but this code doesn't wait for the result

C# code

```cs
WKJavascriptEvaluationResult handler = (NSObject result, NSError error) =>
{
     if (error == null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result.ToString()))
     {
          string resultFromJSCall = result.ToString(); // I'd expect "MyResult"
     };
};

webView.EvaluateJavaScript("test()", handler);
CallBackResult(resultFromJSCall)
```

JavaScript code:

```js
function test() {
     return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve("MyResult"),5000));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript should execute when webview has finished loading, otherwise it will not work .

We can do it in `DidFinishNavigation` method .

```
 webview.NavigationDelegate = new WebViewDelate();

 public class WebViewDelate : WKNavigationDelegate
    {
        public override void DidFinishNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
        {
            WKJavascriptEvaluationResult handler = (NSObject result, NSError error) => {
                if (error != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
                    CallBackResult(result.ToString());
                }
            };
            webView.EvaluateJavaScript("test()", handler);

        }
    }
```

Refer to

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50160111/8187800

Comment: Sorry what does that mean ? Did you try my solution  ？

Comment: Yes, but we are waiting for the result and it executes the next line
the next line means : line after 
webView.EvaluateJavaScript("test()", handler);

for example i want pass result to another method 

CallBackResult(result);

Comment: Place `CallBackResult(result); ` in event `WKJavascriptEvaluationResult ` , call it when get the result . check my update .